# Curl not json response in php

Tags: php

***not getting response using curl. I have put all solution but did not get response.***

```
$ch = curl_init();
$header = array('api_key:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','Content-Type: application/json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);

if($postdata!=""){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
}

$response = curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($response,true);  
print_r($result); // not display result
```

this example not displaying any result but it send to specific place.

Comment: For all who, as I have been looking for a solution:
curl_setopt `($ ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1) ;`: Causes header information to be contained in $ response. Thus, $ response is no longer a pure JSON string.
That's why this non json_decode can be converted into an Object / Array. (Ergnis is null)

My approach: curl_setopt `($ ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);` We refrain from returning the headers and receive a pure JSON that can be further processed.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your code and then check.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);`

For your used-case you have to change your code.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.nhs.uk/organisations/FNM60");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
$result = json_decode($response,true);  
print_r($result);
```

Comment: If your code is not working then do one thing try your curl request through terminal.  Might be the url which you are using is wrong.

Comment: Please share your URL on which you are requesting.

Comment: https://api.nhs.uk/organisations/FNM60

this link get all data using poster and that given response in it. but when i try to using given code that give only 1(one) response.

Comment: Do you want to get just that json? from this URL?

Comment: I want curl result (JSON) inside variable.

Comment: We are already used same code but JSON display top of the before body tag. but we can't take it to any variable

Comment: can you please update your post with expected result?

Comment: Yes we have use you code but giving only 1 as output.

Comment: have got anything on it?

Comment: my code which i have updated in my post is giving this output to me is same as json while hitting this URL https://api.nhs.uk/organisations/FNM60. please do `ini_set("display_errors",1);` on top of your code.

Comment: still not giving output

Comment: @jigneshprajapati Brother it is working fine for me. try this code on https://eval.in/

Comment: I have used that your given link and perform  but it is not working . Actually i got a JSON and display top of the page and we are not echo any statement. but we don't need to that type of output we want in variable so we have take hidden span when start curl and end complete span. but when we try to get data (JSON) in variable it's give only one(1) output , and we are using post request and data is posting properly. but response is not getting.

Comment: have you any solution on that?

Comment: Just do one thing please update you post with Code and Output you are getting.

Comment: Our API key is very confidential i can't share with you , any other solution please?

Comment: No, i am not saying to put those keys, Just put dummy keys and put result you are  getting

Answer (score 0):

here we are getting response without echo on the top of the page but we don't need to that type of out put so we have disabled using span tag.

```
echo "<span style='display:none;'>"; //to hide the curl response
$ch = curl_init();
$header = array('api_key:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','Content-Type: application/json');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
if($postdata!=""){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
}
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$responseBody = json_decode($response);
print_r($responseBody); 
echo $response;  // display 1(one)
curl_close($ch);
echo "</span>";
```

and result is : 1

check full code